# Creating Domain with AWS SimpleDB from Java Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am a university student working on a research project that involves migrating a web application to Amazon's cloud. I spent the last semester working with servlets and was able to get the majority of the app's functionality working using a java servlet running in Tomcat.

I am now trying to integrate Amazon Web Services such as the SimpleDB and E-mail service. I develop using the Eclipse Java EE for Web Developers Indigo IDE. I have the AWS plugin installed and am able to run sample code that Amazon provides to call SDB and SES successfully.

However when I attempt to call a service like simpleDB from the servlet either directly or through a separate class I receive the following error:

> > HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.comtor.cloud.api.APIservlet
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
>     java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
>     java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) note The full stack trace of
>   the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.23

My code looks like this:

```
package org.comtor.cloud.api;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.model.CreateDomainRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class APIservlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      doPost(request, response);
  }
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // AWS Credentials
        String sAccessKey = "myAccessKey";
        String sSecretKey = "mySecretKey";

        // Authenticate AWS account
        BasicAWSCredentials oAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(sAccessKey, sSecretKey);
        AmazonSimpleDBClient awsSimpleDBClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(oAWSCredentials);

        // Try to access simpleDB
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Connecting to Simple Database");
            // Create a domain
            String myDomain = "MyStore";
            System.out.println("Creating domain called " + myDomain + ".\n");
            awsSimpleDBClient.createDomain(new CreateDomainRequest(myDomain));
            System.out.println("Connection Made");

        } 
        // Print Error Stack Trace
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Close PrintWriter
        out.close();
  }
}
```

** Access & Secret Keys removed from code **

The same goes for SES. I have also tried using a java library like 'typica' and still receive a NoClassDef error. I have the AWS library in my build path under the libraries folder and the jar package / classes seem to be there. So I am unsure why I am unable to use these classes to interact with simpleDB from my servlet.

I'd greatly appreciate any help on this matter. I believe I am not fully understanding how to call AWS SDB from a web environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials indicates that this class is not on your classpath.  Make sure that the jar containing the com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials class is included in your web application's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why none of my libraries carried over. They have in the past when I'm using Eclipse. I had to upload the .war manually to my local Tomcat install and place numerous libraries in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Everything was missing from the AWS jar to Apache HTTPcore/client jars. I'm going to look into my Build Path settings and see why the libraries aren't carrying over.

Regardless I did get it working, thank you.