# Amazon Web Services Java classpath

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to run an application that reads and writes to the amazon dynamo DB.  I downloaded the Eclipse toolkit and AWS SDK and if I run the application from my local PC it works perfectly.  Next, I exported it to a jar file and uploaded it to my EC2 instance.  However, when I run it there I get an error.

```
  /home/apps/java/database/bin$ java -jar myJar.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AW                                                                  SCredentials
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: DynamoDB. Program will exit.
```

I assume it has to do with the classpath, but in /home/ubuntu/.bashrc I have set it as such:

```
CLASSPATH="./:/home/apps/java/database/bin/*:/home/apps/java/database/bin/aws-java-sdk-1.3.12.jar"
export CLASSPATH
```

/home/apps/java/database/bin contains all the .jar files that are in the AWS SDK:

- aspectjrt.jar
- aspectjweaver.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.3.12.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.3.12-javadoc.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.3.12-sources.jar
- aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.3.12.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.18.jar
- httpclient-4.1.1.jar
- httpcore-4.1.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.8.7.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.7.jar
- mail-1.4.3.jar
- myJar.jar
- spring-beans-3.0.7.jar
- spring-context-3.0.7.jar
- spring-core-3.0.7.jar
- stax-1.2.0.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar

What am I missing??  I have been looking at this for a day and a half.  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you checked INSIDE the jar file that you created and see what libraries are in there? make sure all the necessary aws jar file are actually included in your jar file

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936274/creating-domain-with-aws-simpledb-from-java-servlet

Comment: I've also tried building the jar without the classpath file.  Shouldn't this default everything to the unix server?  The classpath file that eclipse builds looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.AWS_JAVA_SDK"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>`

Comment: I've even tried explicitly listing all the jar files in my CLASSPATH env var and running it with `java -cp $CLASSPATH -jar myJar.jar`  

Still no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath entry of "/directory/*" may be messing things up. Classpaths are separated with colons, but asterisk expansion gives spaces. Try this little shell script to start it.

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx4G"
CP=`find /home/apps/java/database/bin/*jar -exec echo -n "{}:" \;`
java -cp ${CP%?} -jar yourjar.jar
```

A couple of notes:

- the JAVA_OPTS is only there as a reminder that you may need more memory than the default.
- the crazy syntax for CP on the final line strips the last character, since the "find" line is leaving a colon on the end.
- You may want to include your jar and launch the correct class if it isn't an executable jar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I am still getting the same error when I try to run the 4th line in your suggestion.  
`java -cp ${CP%?} -jar myJar.jar` 
and I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException`.

I also tried adding /directory/*jar in the .bashrc file with no additional luck.  Any more thoughts?  Thank you

Comment: add the results of "echo $CP" to your original question so we/I can see the output.

Comment: I was eventually able to get it to work with java -cp $CLASSPATH myMainClassName
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This list of libs works for me
    aws-java-sdk-1.11.285-javadoc.jar
    aws-java-sdk-1.11.285-sources.jar
    aws-java-sdk-1.11.285.jar
    aws-java-sdk.jar

```
aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
aws-swf-build-tools-1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.9.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
ion-java-1.0.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jarÅ
jackson-core-2.6.7.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar
javax.mail-api-1.4.6.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.285.jar
joda-time-2.8.1.jar
netty-buffer-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-codec-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-codec-http-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-handler-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-resolver-4.1.17.Final.jar
netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar
spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```